# How to use Python dataframe and SQLAlchemy to create MySQL tables

Tags: dataframe, sqlalchemy

I have to create few tables in database called 'data_immo'. To that purpose, I'm using data frames (each DataFrame corresponding to one table), MySql and SqlAlchemy.
Here is my code:

```
header_Bien_Immo = ['LotNb']
df_Bien_Immo = df1.loc[:, header_Bien_Immo]
df_Bien_Immo['IdLot'] = IdLot
df_Bien_Immo.index.names = ['IdBien']

def con_engine():url = "mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@localhost"
    engine = create_engine(url.format(user='root', password='Fer458it'))
    engine.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS data_immo")
    return

def create_table(df):
    df.to_sql(name='bien_immo', con=con_engine(), if_exists='append', index=False,
          dtype={'LotNb': Integer,
                 'IdLot': Integer,
                 'IdBien': Integer})
    return


con_engine()
create_table(df_Bien_Immo)'''
```

The execution of that code returns an error:

line 2214, in to_sql
raise ValueError(f"{col} ({my_type}) not a string")
ValueError: LotNb (<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.Integer'>) not a string.

Would you have any idea what the problem is ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

con_engine() function provides elements to create connection and database itself. Then, to create table we have to provide engine with database name. This is what was missing.

```
def con_engine():
    url = "mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@localhost"
    engine = create_engine(url.format(user='root', password='Fer458it'))
    engine.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS data_immo")
    return


def create_table(df):
    url = "mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@localhost/{db}"
    engine = create_engine(url.format(user='root', password='Fer458it', db='data_immo'))
    df.to_sql(name='Lot', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=True,
              dtype={'LotNom': VARCHAR(10), 'LotType': Text, 'LotValeurFonciere': Integer, 'LotSurfBati': Integer,
              'LotSurfCarrez': DECIMAL(6, 2), 'LotNbPieces': Integer, 'LotSuperJardin': Integer})
    return


con_engine()
create_table(df_Lot)
```